# can't upload a big file to persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I created a persistent volume, claim (10Gi) and mounted on a pod. Below are the YAML file.
[YAML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDMci.png)

My intention is to upload a big file to persistent volume by

```
kuberctl cp [local file path] namespace/pod_name:/mount_path
```

I expected the mount path should be of 10Gi (as of PV). Instead it's 4KB. hence I can not upload a big file.

Below is the error when I try to upload a big file:

```
tar: file_name: Wrote only 2560 of 10240 bytes
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
command terminated with exit code 2
```

Which is I guess because directories doesn't have space. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide additional information about your storage class `manual`? I found nothing in documentation about this storage class.

Comment: I followed the reference from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/.. I'm relatively new to Kubernetes and docker.

Comment: Is folder `/mnt/disk` exist or kubernetes allow to write there? Because all is fine with configs